# Через функцию добавить элементы массива

Tags: массивы, функции, swift

Нужно в заданный пустой массив [String] через функцию добавить и удалить элементы

```
func addCountries(countries: [String]) {
    var name1 = "Jamaica"
    var name2 = "Spain"
    var newCountries = countries
    newCountries.append(name2)
}
```

Этот способ добавляет конечно элемент в массив, но при повторном вызове функции с заданным параметром - массив уже получается с 2 значениями.
Вопрос - что не так в теле функции, что изменить, чтоб одной командой добавлять в массив значение

Comment: Не понятно, что именно вас не устраивает. Я повторно вызываю функцию и массив не получается с двумя значениями. Напишите пожалуйста, в тексте вопроса, пример кода, как вы вызываете функцию и как вы видите, что "массив уже получается с 2 значениями", т. е. что-то выводится в консоль, или что-то типа того.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 var countries = [String]()
func addCountries(countries: [String]) {
    var name2 = "Spain"
    var newCountries = countries
    newCountries.append(name2)
}


func deleteCoutries(coutries:[String]) {
    var sameCountries = coutries
    var name = "Russia"
    for i in sameCountries {
        if i == name {
            sameCountries.append(i)
        } else {
            print ("ERROR")
        }
        
    }
}
```

Вот так в итоге реализовал добавление и удаление значений из пустых массивов через функции

Comment: А Вы пробовали запускать Ваш код? Он же не будет ничего добавлять или удалять из вашего ВНЕШНЕГО массива, потому что все изменения происходят ВНУТРИ функций и никак не возвращаются из них наружу. Они никак не влияют на содержимое массива , объявленного в первой строчке кода.